# uploading xml string

Tags: xml, ajax

Edit:
I want to know suppose if there's another way to upload the xml content without passing it as a POST parameter. is this possible?

I currently have a client app that manipulates an xml file, then wants to upload its content back to the server,  If I uploaded back as a get/post string in an ajax call, is there a limitation as to how big the string is?
is there other way?

Answer (score 1):

The limits on get/post string length are both theoretical and vary between browsers and servers.

For sending a large chunk of data though, like an xml file, or for sending any data that would result in a change in stored data on the server you should use a post request.  You shouldn't have to worry about the size limit of the post string unless you know your server is configured to allow ridiculously small amounts of post data or that your xml file is heinously, unimaginably large.

Comment: so if I have like a 10mg xml file, it's ok to send its content string as a parameter in the post?

Comment: if your server will allow it. but it seems like there should be a better way to do what your trying to do.  The question should be: How do i do what im trying to do without having to download and re-upload 10 megs worth of xml in the browser?